# How to do software versions with phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I am considering using phabricator but I noticed the tasks lacks a version field and I was wondering: How are software version usually handled within phabricator? Every version is a new project? Or a version is a new workboard inside a project? Or a custom field added to a task?

Jira, for instance, has a 'fix version' and when you release a version you can use this to compile a list of things which changed in the new version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the recommended approach right now is to have each version as a new project, yes (see, e.g., the checkered flag icons you can use on projects). Alternatively, a custom field is probably also OK.

For more concrete release management, I think Releeph might be the application that will eventually support this?
https://secure.phabricator.com/tag/releeph/

It's a prototype application, though, so "use at own risk" and all that.